# jQuery Mobile Menu Accordion Not Working Properly

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, navigation, accordion

I'm trying to set up a jquerymobile site and i'm having a little trouble with the accordion menu on the front page, Here is a working example of the accordion without jquerymobile: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22874377/Mobile/accordion.html but when used with jquerymobile it doesn't work as seen here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22874377/Mobile/app.html

Pretty much what's happening is even though I have it set as an accordion it forces the page transitions from jquerymobile and trys to load the child list items as if they were contained on a separate page

Any ideas as to why this might be? or what i can do to work around it?

here is the simple script if you don't want to view the working examples

```
<style>
#nav li ul {
display: none; // used to hide sub-menus
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
  if (checkCookie != "") {
    $('#nav > li > a:eq('+checkCookie+')').next().show();
  }
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
      var navIndex = $('#nav > li > a').index(this);
      $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
       if ($(this).next().is(":visible")){
       $(this).next().slideUp();
       } else {
       $(this).next().slideToggle();
       }
   });
}); 
</script>
<ul id="nav" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#home" data-transition="flip">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c" data-icon="arrow-d">
                    <a href="#">
                        Info
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                    <li data-theme="c"><a href="#" data-transition="flip">About Katie</a></li>
                    <li data-theme="c"><a href="#" data-transition="flip">Availability</a></li>
                    <li data-theme="c"><a href="#" data-transition="flip">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li data-theme="c"><a href="#" data-transition="flip">Contact</a></li>
                    <li data-theme="c"><a href="#" data-transition="flip">Downloads</a></li>
                    <li data-theme="c"><a href="#home" data-transition="flip">Back to Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#home" data-transition="flip">
                        Galleries
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c" data-icon="arrow-d">
                    <a href="#home" data-transition="flip">
                        Client Proofs
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                    <li data-them="c"><a href="#" data-transition="flip">Monica &amp; Andrew's Excellent Wedding</a></li>
                    <li data-theme="c"><a href="#home" data-transition="flip">Back to Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-theme="c">
                    <a href="#home" data-transition="flip">
                        Testimonials
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: You should catch clicks on an already expanded tab and do nothing. Since right now you can make it animate like crazy by clicking on the same tab. Also, since it queues up you can click like twenty times in a row and just watch it animate for a while.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not quite sure what you're trying to say? if you look at the examples you will see what i mean by the functionality, it works just fine on the non jquerymobile example but when i use jquerymobile it does not fire the accordion properly

Comment: okay so i've corrected the animation issue by adding a simple cookie if you go look at the non jquerymobile accordion now, the real question is how do i actually resolve the problem at hand? which is the non functioning in jquerymobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quickly, just by inspecting your different link element in the exemple, you can see they have 
home&ui-page=nav-(a number)  as href attribute, which cause it to open a new page : ...Mobile/app.html#home&ui-page=nav-0

this is why it opens in a new page, the href attributes should be empty (or #) since you wont be using it to navigate your site and simply use it to activate the slide up-down ...

(as for why they get this, its probably because of your automatic UI ... but I cant help you there )

Comment: the funny thing is even when i removed the a href attribute and simply left it as an li, it still opens it in a new page

Comment: if you look at the code you will also notice that the href attributes are all empty or set to # except for the primary one which goes to the homepage and the back to homepage buttons

Comment: yea but when you use UI ( like jqueryUI) it automaticly adds up some class and my guess wouldbe that your jquerymobile add those link at the end of your href element ... when you remove the &ui-page  blabla from the href it doesnt open in a new page tough. any place where you can read the doc of that jquerymobile ?

Comment: no worries, i appreciate it! and i figured it out, just had to rewrite everything and mimic the styling. the styles being applied by the data-role="listview" was causing the conflicts

Comment: hehe yea, I find that out once I started working, styles always create problems somewhere ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
  $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
 }
```

});

the document should be in quotes

```
$('document').ready(function () {
```

Comment: that is obviously not the problem as you can see it works just fine on the non jquerymobile version

Comment: i did test it, it still doesn't resolve the issue unfortunately, btw i've never really used 'document' in this way, only document when calling a function and it's always worked..

Comment: you need to import jQuery since slideUp and slideToggle functions are defined in jQuery and not in jQuerymobile

Comment: lol, just look at the code.. jquery is already imported a mobile site wouldn't actually function properly without calling the jquery for some additional required background functions